# How to set item inside Places Bar in windows file explorer

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

In windows file Explorer you have a pane on the left side (Places Bar):

[image]

How can I add something to this.

*And no I am not asking about "quick access" or "Favorites". I am aware of those I want to completely add my own item.*

Comment: I think **it is called the 'places bar'** if so read from step 5 in this link http://www.thewindowsclub.com/add-folders-favorite-links-windows-file-explorer

Answer (score 0):

*This does not solve your problem, so I am marking it as **Community Wiki** in hopes that I'm wrong and somebody has a real answer.*

I was interested in this myself and put several hours of research into it. There were various registry changes suggested on the internet and I attempted a few of them, but none of them worked for me.  I eventually decided that it wasn't possible, and have resigned myself to using *Quick Access*.

In my research, I did find a somewhat hidden setting for the navigation bar in "Folder Options".  You can open the settings from any explorer folder (View >> Options), and find the 3 options here:

[image]